# Get if drive in /etc/fstab without root

Tags: fstab

Is there a way too find if a drive is in /etc/fstab, without root? I want to know if I can run just `sudo mount /dev/sdx` and it will get the mountpoint from /etc/fstab, without running the command and before running sudo.

I found there's `mount --fake` (on GNU) but it requires sudo.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from reading `/etc/fstab/`? My experience is that usually the permissions on it are `644`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `/etc/fstab` is world-readable, so you can just `cat /etc/fstab` and see if it's there.

The partitions may be listed in `/etc/fstab` by LABEL, UUID, PARTLABEL, or PARTUUID instead of by the device path. In this case, you might not be sure if any of the entries correspond to `/dev/sdx` or not. Running `blkid /dev/sdx` should show you this information about the partition, if you have permission. (Non-root users may need to be in the `disk` group, or whatever group owns `/dev/sdx`.) If you don't have such permission, you can still see what device e.g. `UUID=aa1a69af-0bad-48b8-a659-95f1daceaceb` corresponds to by `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ stat -c '%a %A %n' /etc/fstab
```

is echoing:

> ```
> 644 -rw-r--r-- /etc/fstab
> ```

at least on Linux Mint 19.2 based on Ubuntu Bionic.

---

**Every user on the system can read the [fstab file (wiki)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).**